# Creating Mysql database with python - keep getting 1064 error (... right syntax to use near '%s' )

Tags: python, mysql, sql, syntax-error, ddl

Here is the thing:
I'm trying to make a new MySQL database by importing the name for the database and then creating it.

Here is the code:

```
import mysql.connector as mcon

# DB Connect
stdb = mcon.connect(
    host        = "localhost",
    user        = "root",
    password    = "pass",
    database    = "trffc_int_data")
cursor = stdb.cursor()

# Creating new DB
NewDB = input(" Enter the Database name : ")
sqlsynt = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS %s"
cursor.execute(sqlsynt,NewDB)                 
cursor.commit()
print ("New database created!")
```

Looks right, but I keep getting error "1065 >> *You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s'*<<"

It points the line: `cursor.execute(sqlsynt,NewDB)`

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind object names (in this case - the database name) like that, only values. You'll have to resort to string formatting. E.g.:

```py
newDB = input(" Enter the Database name : ")
sqlsynt = f"CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {newDB}"
cursor.execute(sqlsynt,NewDB)
```